# how to get the form name Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

How can i get the input name

Here is my code

```
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    alert(e.name); //this is giving me undefined
    uploadFiles('upload.php', this.files, e.name);
}, false);
```

The 1st input file

```
<input type="file" class="textbox" name="webinar_image" id="webinar_logo" style="margin-top: 20px;" />
```

The 2nd input file

```
<input type="file" class="textbox" name="webinar_logo" id="webinar_logo"  style="margin-top: 20px;" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is available as `this` inside an event handler, so use `this.name`.